# rspec expected #count to have changed by 1, but was changed by 0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I have the following in my locations_controller_spec.rb:

```
describe 'create' do
 it 'should create the record' do
   expect do
     post :create, params: { location: FactoryBot.attributes_for(:location) }
   end.to change(Location, :count).by(1)
 end
end
```

My locations factory has:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :location do
    name              'MyString'
    hours_operation   'MyString'
    abbreviation      'MyString'
    address_1         'MyString'
    address_2         'MyString'
    city              'MyString'
    state             'MyString'
    postal_code       1
    phone             'MyString'
    fax               'MyString'
    association       :region
  end
end
```

I seeded the database to get rid of an issue with region needing to exist but now I'm getting:

```
Admin::LocationsController create should create the record
 Failure/Error:
   expect do
     post :create, params: { location: FactoryBot.attributes_for(:location) }
   end.to change(Location, :count).by(1)
```

What am I missing? Locations are storing.

EDIT: Here's the controller that's causing the issue:

```
def create
 @region = Region.find(params[:region_id])
 @location = @region.location.new(location_params)
 flash[:notice] = 'Location created successfully'if @region.location << @location
 respond_with @location, location: admin_locations_path
end
```

Comment: Presumably, there are errors on the `location` you are trying to create. You could do `create!` or `puts @location.errors` or `debug` or something like that to suss out what the errors are.

Comment: @jvillian totally right and usually figure out this issue by debugging rspec by setting a binding pry and installing pry for test

Comment: This is probably a sign that your controller is not actually creating the item like you want. I suspect your test is working properly but something in your controller code is messed up. Can you paste the code for your controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had messed with the controller's create method. It worked once I switched it back:

```
def create
 @location = Location.new(location_params)
 flash[:notice] = 'Location created successfully' if @location.save
 respond_with @location, location: admin_locations_path
end
```